# Redirect to custom 500 error page

Tags: sitecore-forms, error-handling

We are using `Sitecore 9.3` We have setup `custom 500 error page` on the portal and it works fine for application errors.

But it does not redirect to the custom 500 error page for the below link -

```
https://portalname.com/formbuilder?sc_site=SSP_DLL_BE&fxb.FormItemId=f2a1e647-ede2-4649-81c3-2d5e73d662f3&fxb.HtmlPrefix=fxb.5a7f68ef-76f2-49d1-9cd1-edb1d4f68885
```

[image]

**Error in logs -**

```
at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
   at Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc.Pipelines.RenderForm.InitializeAjaxOptions.Process(RenderFormEventArgs args)
   at (Object , Object )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline[TArgs](String pipelineName, TArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline[TArgs,TResult](String pipelineName, TArgs args, Func`2 resultGetter)
   at Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc.Html.HtmlExtensions.BeginRenderRouteForm(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, FormViewModel model, Boolean isPost)
   at ASP._Page_Views_FormBuilder_Form_cshtml.Execute() in S:\inetpub\sc93vfssp\Views\FormBuilder\Form.cshtml:line 6
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
```

How to redirect to custom 500 error page in case of errors in experience forms?

Comment: Is this a custom submit action on Sitecore Forms?

Comment: @SumitUpadhyay yes we have created custom submit action. It works as expected but if we make the same call twice explicitly on the browser then it gives runtime error. This runtime error is not redirecting to custom 500 error page.

Comment: Prevent your form from redirecting to the default Form Builder page and create your custom page for validation checks and "thank you" message, see [this article](https://sitecorediaries.org/2020/08/26/avoid-sitecore-form-redirecting-to-forms-builder-page/) for more details

Comment: Thanks @KateOrlova. I want custom 500 error page to be shown in case of error mentioned in the description. Can you suggest how to do that?

Comment: @NewbieHere, you already have the error handling in place in the front-end and your custom 500 error page will be picked up automatically once you have created a custom page for your form validation checks and "thank you" message